# Writing normal C++ String to Rapid JSON is resulting in string with backslash

Tags: c++, rapidjson

```
string str = {"appId":"com.mymusic.app","Connectivity":True,"DistractionLevel":2,"display":True};

if(!str.empty())
{
StringBuffer bf;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer (bf);
writer.StartObject();
writer.Key("info"));
writer.String(str.c_str());
writer.EndObject();    
cout<<"request string is:" , (char *)bf.GetString());

}
```

cout is printing the below line with back slash

```
{"info":"\"appId\":\"com.mymusic.app\",\"checkConnectivity\":True,\"driverDistractionLevel\":2,\"display\":True}"}
```

What i was expecting is

```
{"info": {"appId":"com.mymusic.app","Connectivity":True,"DistractionLevel":2,"display":True} }
```

Comment: That isn't valid C++ code. Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: `string str = {"appId":"com...` does not compile.

Comment: string str = {"appId":"com.mymusic.app","Connectivity":True,"DistractionLevel":2,"display":True}; is invalid declaration. I knew this.

I am performing parsing as below and finally i am creating a string like above.
for (auto& m : itr->value.GetObject())
{
if(m.name.GetString())  {
do somethi
} else if(xxx){
do something
}
}

Comment: Why are you expecting to insert an object when you added a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the the wrong function. The `String` function will add a string value to the json-object and in this context the escaping of `"` to `\"` is expected.

I think what you actually want to do is add the string as a json-sub-object. From what I found in the rapidjson documentation the function you want to use for that is [RawValue](https://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_writer.html#a8acb89b2bbb1e5f384e6076b65044dbe).